# Is there some text mode browser that supports at least basic javascript?

Tags: linux, browser, javascript

I looked at links2 and elinks - neither one seems to even support a simple javascript redirect on a site.

Any ideas? Is there some sort of text mode for some opensource browser e.g. Firefox that I can compile and use?

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think there are any.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this information](http://elinks.or.cz/documentation/manual.html#ecmascript) regarding how you can add JavaScript (ECMAScript) support to [elinks](http://elinks.or.cz).

Answer (score -1):

> Is there some sort of text mode for some opensource browser e.g. Firefox that I can compile and use?

Depends what you mean by text mode. You can turn off images and plugins in any modern browser, no recompile needed. It'll still require a graphical display and plenty of RAM though.

Comment: In text mode I mean in a simple terminal session, no X window or other graphical display.